# Show featuring characters who are a part of a special order who fight with swords from around the 90s

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a show with characters who are a part of a special order or something.

The weapons are swords. They duel and the loser gets the head chopped off. Decapitated. Then thunder rolls usually after the kill.

It is set in modern day times which was the 90s at the time I believe.

I think they have trench coats.

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 44):

That would be [Highlander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(franchise)), [the Series. (1992 - 1997)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander:_The_Series)

It was a spin off from the Movies of the same name, and spun two additional shows off of it, as well.  (The base series, the Raven, and, believe it or not, an Animated Series.)

The thunder you are remembering (and usually a lightning strike) are part of getting '[The Quickening](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quickening)', after defeating another immortal.

Be careful -- this link could lose you hours of productive time.. But the [TvTropes page on Highlander (Series)](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Highlander) may help confirm this is what you a remembering.  [The Highlander Wiki](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page), too, may be of interest.

[image: Highlander Cover Image]

Comment: Suddenly I'm feeling really old...

Comment: @JohnHunt I guess you don't "have inside [you] blood of kings," huh? :)

Comment: As they say, "there should have been only one"... :D

Comment: @AnoE: that is in reference to the Highlander movie? That is an understatement!...

Comment: @olivierdulac, yup. I mean the first one was legendary (in its time) due to the Queen music alone, and Sir Sean Connery... a case for when it would have been perfectly fine to let good be good enough and end it there, IMO.

Comment: @JohnHunt Reminds me of that question seeking an ID of the movie featuring a boy in a desert who turns on a robot he built himself, impressing two visitors, one of whom dies in a war, which turned out to be "Phantom Menace."

Comment: @AnoE yeah but then we wouldn't have had all the sweet, sweet weirdness that came from the second movie

Comment: @jeffronicus I was hurt with this question, your comment killed me.